# The running results of program which has the same code are different under different platforms

Tags: c

I write such code to help me understand the usage of `realloc()` function. Maybe there are some problems in the follow code.

```
 1 #include <stdio.h>
 2 #include <stdlib.h>
 3 #include <string.h>
 4 
 5 
 6 void dynamic_memory_management_func()
 7 {
 8     printf("------------dynamic_memory_management_func------------\n");
 9 
10     char *str1 = (char *)malloc(16);
11     memset(str1, 0, 16);
12     strcpy(str1, "0123456789AB");
13     char *str2 = realloc(str1, 8);
14     
15     printf("str1 value: %p [%s]\n", str1, str1);
16     printf("str2 value: %p [%s]\n", str2, str2);
17     
18     free(str2);
19     str2 = NULL;
20     
21     char *str3 = (char *)malloc(16);
22     memset(str3, 0, 16);
23     strcpy(str3, "0123456789AB");
24     char *str4 = realloc(str3, 64); 
25     strcpy(str4 + 12, "CDEFGHIJKLMN");
26     
27     printf("str3 value: %p [%s]\n", str3, str3);
28     printf("str4 value: %p [%s]\n", str4, str4);
29     
30     free(str4);
31     str4 = NULL;
32 
33 }
34 
35 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
36 {
37     dynamic_memory_management_func();
38     return 0;
39 }
```

To my surprise，the running result of program are different!

Under mac os x 10.9.2, the result is：

```
------------dynamic_memory_management_func------------
str1 value: 0x7ff7f1c03940 [0123456789AB]
str2 value: 0x7ff7f1c03940 [0123456789AB]
str3 value: 0x7ff7f1c03940 [0123456789AB]
str4 value: 0x7ff7f1c03950 [0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMN]
```

Under ubuntu 12.04 LTS, the result is:

```
------------dynamic_memory_management_func------------
str1 value: 0xf6e010 [0123456789AB]
str2 value: 0xf6e010 [0123456789AB]
str3 value: 0xf6e010 [0123456789ABCDEFGHIGKLMN]
str4 value: 0xf6e010 [0123456789ABCDEFGHIGKLMN]
```

As you've seen, The addresses of pointer of str4 are different. What make it happened?

Comment: If you ask two people to pick a T-shirt, would you expect both of them to pick a pink one?

Comment: This reminds me, SO should generate automatic line numbers with code in the question.

Comment: `realloc()` can return a different address than it was called with even when it is shrinking memory. The important thing to remember is that, if it does not return `NULL`, the old address (if changed) is invalid.

Comment: @pmg Hey guy，I have remove the shrinking operation.

Comment: A version without UB works fine at [ideone](http://ideone.com/Ilq1XM).

Comment: I should have checked the return value of `malloc()` and `realloc()` calls in that ideone program.

Comment: @pmg But the program running on mac os x 10.9.2.The str4 pointer is still different from the result show on [ideone](http://ideone.com/Ilq1XM).

Comment: `realloc()` can change the address no matter what. You have no control over that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's an expected result.

The memory `malloc()` chooses each time it is called depends on many many things. It probably chooses different memory on the same computer at different times! Let alone on different computers.

The important thing is the contents of the memory. And they're (about) the same, as expected, on your test.

**However you have a few errors**:

line 15: `str1` is invalid. It has been made invalid be the previous call to `realloc()`.

line 16: the contents of `str2` are not a "string". it does not have a proper terminator. It is invalid to print it with `printf()`

line 27: `str3` is invalid. It has been made invalid be the previous call to `realloc()`.

Comment: The complier do complain nothing.

Comment: Nevertheless, they are Undefined Behaviour. Undefined Behaviour may not be caught by the compiler, it may not be caught when running the program. You should avoid UB at all costs.

Comment: @lojunren also, you should not cast the result of `malloc` or `realloc`.

Comment: **After your edit** @Line 16: you cannot print `str2` with `printf()` and `"%s"` because `str2` is not a string; it has no zero terminator. Once you do that, UB has been invoked and anything can happen.

Comment: @ajay I rewrite my code and reedit my question.But the result are still different.

Comment: @pmg Could you explain to me why the results of str4 are different?

Comment: I only see difference in `str3` ... but after you invoked **UB** (at line 16) there really is no explanation.

Comment: It may be of benefit to you to maxize your level of compiler warnings.